# Subscribe to a BehaviorSubject untill value is not undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service with a value of BehaviorSubject. I am accessing this value from my service in a TS page. I use this portion of code:

Basically if SubjectVariable is not undefined I am adding this value to my local variable of SubjectVariableNew. 
I want to loop this until the SubjectVariable !== undefined for a timeout of 3 seconds. If in this time period its undefined i will pop up a text message. So basically i want to have 3 seconds time window/loading and check if the SubjectVariable !== undefined.

```
this.myService.mySubjectVariable.subscribe((SubjectVariable: 
string) => {     
            if (SubjectVariable !== undefined) {
                this.SubjectVariableNew = SubjectVariable;
                this.valueIsReturned = true;
            } else {
                this.valueIsReturned = false;
            }

});
```

Comment: *"I want to loop"*. What do you mean ? You subscribe to a BehaviorSubject, the subscription will last until your BehaviorSubject completes or you close the subscription.

Comment: Why the timeouts? Just "wait" for it and do the actions with the variable inside the `subscribe`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [timeout](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html) and [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operators:

```
    const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    subject
      .pipe(
        filter(data => data !== null)
      )
     .pipe(
        timeout(3000),
        catchError(error => of(`Request timed out!`))
      )
      .subscribe(
        () => console.log("Data is not null")
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use retryWhen to retry with a delay. Here is an example :

```js
const sub = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject(undefined);

setTimeout(() => sub.next('Hey'), 1500);

sub.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.map(value => {
    if (value) return value;
    throw 'Error: value is undefined';
  }),
  rxjs.operators.retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
    rxjs.operators.tap(error => console.log('retrying for error = ', error)),
    rxjs.operators.delay(1000),
    rxjs.operators.take(2),
  ))
).subscribe(
  value => console.log('value has been set'),
  error => console.log('value has been kept to undefined'),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```